# Value of a such that the system has no solution/infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have this system of equations here:

$Ax=b$, where:

$A=$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\ 1 & 3 & 4\\ 
\ 1 & a & 5\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$

$b=$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\ a\\ 
\ 3\\ 
\ 3\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$

I have to find the values of $a$ in which the system has no solution and the value of a in which the system has infinitely many solutions.

I wrote my augmented matrix as:

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\ 1 & 2 & 3 & a \\ 
\ 1 & 3 & 4 & 3\\ 
\ 1 & a & 5 & 3\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$

I then attempted to row reduce and then do cases but after a certain point, I am stuck. So far, I've row reduced down to:

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\ 1 & 2 & 3 & a \\ 
\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3-a\\ 
\ 0 & a-2 & 2 & 3-a\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$

I'm not really sure what to do after this point though. I should probably row reduce more but I'm stuck on how I would show the conditions for each case of a. If anyone could guide me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here you can use the 1 in row 2 column 2 to zero out the rest of column 2, still without assumptions on a. Then see what it becomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue reducing!

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\ 1 & 2 & 3 & a \\ 
\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3-a\\ 
\ 0 & a-2 & 2 & 3-a\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)\longrightarrow\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\ 1 & 2 & 3 & a \\ 
\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3-a\\ 
\ 0 & 0 & 4-a & (a-3)^2\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)$$

Can you prove that for $\;a=4\;$ you get an incongruent system (no solution)? What happens if $\;a\neq4\;$ ?

Comment: I get that there is no possible value for a in which there are infinitely many solutions. I don't think it's possible to write one row as a multiple of another in any way.

Comment: @FutureMathperson Right. if $\;a=4\;$ there is no solution, and $\;a\neq4\;$ renders a coefficient matrix that is regular, which means unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

After subtracting $a-2$ times row 2 from row 3, the (3,3) entry is $2-(a-2)=4-a.$ That is zero iff $a=4.$ So if $a=4$ there will be 0 or infinitely many solutions. In row 3 column 4 it will be $(3-a)-(3-a)(a-2)=(3-a)[1-(a-2)]=(3-a)^2$ which isn't $0$ when $a=4.$ So if your calculation so far is right, no solutions.

Thanks to Don Antonio for fix.

Comment: In row $3$ column $4$ it must be $$(3-a)[1-a+2]=(3-a)^2=(a-3)^2$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for fix. Put it in, with note.

Comment: After mulling this over for a bit, I don't think there is a case where we have infinitely many solutions actually. That would mean I could write one row as a multiple of another row, but that's impossible for any choice of $a$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, no a gives infinitely many solutions. the only possible value 4 of a gives no solutions.